# Integrating Google Speech-to-Text on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm planning to make a **live stream website on Wordpress**, and I was planning on **using the Google Speech-to-Text** API to **auto caption the live stream** as it is broadcasting on Wordpress. I'm not sure if the concept is entirely possible to do using the Google Speech-to-Text,

The question now being:

1. Is this concept doable with the current Google Speech-to-Text API?
2. If it is, can the Google Speech-to-Text receive input from a live streaming video in the website (rather than usually input from a microphone)?
3. Would it also work on live stream video playback as well?
4. Where do I start to implement the API?
5. If Google Speech-to-Text can't work for something like this, is there an alternative?

I appreciate any help I can get, as I'm starting to get a little desperate. Appreciate as well if you guys can use simple English since it isn't my first language.

Comment: I think your question is really broad and not suited for stack overflow.

Comment: @FabiandePabian can you point out which part do I need to specify on? and if that's not the case, do you know which site that I can go to to get this kind of help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go that with Streaming Recognize: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize